# Most used parts of Boost

Tags: c++, boost

When I discovered [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) I thought to myself "why didn't I know about this sooner!" - I hated having to write code like

```
stringstream ss;
ss << anIntVal;
mystring = ss.str();
```

Now I write

```
mystring = boost::lexical_cast<string>(anIntVal);
```

Yesterday, on stackoverflow, I came across boost split (another gem that will save me writing code).

```
string stringtobesplit = "AA/BB-CC")
vector<string> tokens;

boost::split(tokens, stringtobesplit, boost::is_any_of("/-")); 
// tokens now holds 3 items: AA BB CC
```

I am going to start looking through boost documentation looking for other functions that I will be able to use regularly, but I feel that it will be very easy to miss things.

What boost functions do you use most / would hate not to have?

Comment: Out of interest, what stopped you writing your own "convert number to string" function before you used Boost? I'd have seen the duplication and written a simple template and used that and then, perhaps, switched to the boost version when I found it...

Comment: Hi Len, At different times on different projects I have written a templated "ToStr" function, but then I would move on to some other project, then end up writing the 3-liner because I just wanted to get the darn thing done :-) as opposed to the overhead of creating a "misc_funcs" file

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Probably the most used part of boost for me is [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Comment: Also probably most over-used. I have myself learnt the lesson the hard way by having to refactor out most of the usages of shared_ptr by references, pointer containers and auto_ptr. I now mostly agree to this: http://www.bureau14.fr/blogea/index.php/2009/08/smart-pointers-are-overused/

Comment: @phaedrus: Updated link: https://blogea.bureau14.fr/index.php/2009/08/smart-pointers-are-overused/

Comment: No longer relevant in C++11 which has `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 51):

[BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/foreach.html) makes life worthwhile again.

(Why has nobody mentioned this? The question was asked 8 months ago!)

Comment: Eric Niebler's article on "Conditional Love" (http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html) describes how BOOST_FOREACH works. It's pretty crazy.

Comment: No longer so popular with C++11 and lambdas...

Answer (score 39):

My faves are, in no particular order:

- regex
- [filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)
- thread
- [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)
- program_options (just brilliant!)
- test (for all my unit testing needs).
- String algorithms
- String tokenizer
- format (type-safe printf style string formatting)
- smart ptrs

Boost was a massive help when I wrote my first cross-platform app - without it I really would have struggled.

Comment: Please update for C++11/C++14...

Answer (score 29):

I like how you can supply your own destructor for `shared_ptr`.
This means, for example, you can use it with `FILE*` and get it to close the file for you.
eg

```
void safeclose(FILE*fp) {
    if(fp) {
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
void some_fn() {
    boost::shared_ptr<FILE> fp( fopen(myfilename, "a+t"), safeclose );
    //body of the function, and when ever it exits the file gets closed
    fprintf( fp.get(), "a message\n" );
}
```

Comment: I know it's nearly two years later, but... that assignment to `NULL` is useless, as it assigns the local function parameter. :)

Comment: Thanks @Xeo, I have removed it

Answer (score 22):

Nobody has mentioned [Multi-Index Containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) so I'll chime in late. It's not that often that you need them, but without boost it is a real pain to create an equivalent data structure, as well as being less efficient. I've been using them a lot recently to create containers that have look up on 2 keys.

Answer (score 20):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned `boost::optional`. I find myself using it more often than any part of Boost except `shared_ptr` and `scoped_ptr`.

Comment: Now available as `std::experimental::optional` and soon (C++17?) as `std::optional`.

Comment: Yup, and I'm very happy about it. :-) Though considering the delay between the standards and full implementation of them in all the compilers I use, it'll still be a while before I can depend on it... I was just able to start using C++11 on a project last year. :-(

Comment: Actually I think most compilers are ok w.r.t. meeting standards in recent years - GCC and clang supported C++14 when it was released, didn't they? Anyway, please consider integrating your comment into your answer.

Comment: @HeadGeek Interesting to see a new comment added to your answer after 8 years, and you responded!

Comment: Wow... I guess it *has* been eight years. As Kermit the Frog says, time's fun when you're having flies. ;-)

Comment: Now available as `std::optional` in C++ 17

Answer (score 19):

Nobody mentions boost::tuple? For shame!

Comment: Now available as `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 11):

[`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html)

**Update** (October 2011): C++11 (C++0x) has `static_assert` http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#static_assert

Comment: BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG allows very easy to read/spot errors that are far more informative than the sizeof incomplete type message that BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT gives.

Comment: here here! I just found one of these incomplete type errors inside the testing macro BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE - took me half a day to figure out what was going on before I twigged that I'd called it with (int,int,float); once I cast the integers to floating point the error went away. But what that has to do with an incomplete type I really don't know :)

Answer (score 9):

One of my most used is not in Boost proper, but the [Adobe Source Libraries (ASL)](http://stlab.adobe.com/asl_toc.html) built on top of Boost — specifically, the extensions to the standard algorithms that accept a boost::range in place of separate begin/end iterators. Then instead of calling, say,

```
std::for_each(some_container.begin(), some_container.end(), do_something());
```

I can simply say

```
adobe::for_each(some_container, do_something());
```

(I do hope these parts of ASL migrate to Boost eventually.)

Comment: I like it, I shall check out the ASL

Answer (score 8):

I use a lot:

- boost::signals
- boost::shared_ptr
- boost::lexical_cast
- boost::bind
- boost::random
- boost::thread
- boost::noncopyable

Other like Tuple, Static Assert and Integer are very useful if you are writing a library which is due to be used on a variety of platforms.

Things like Graphs and Lambda are more specific.

Comment: Please update for these days of C++11/14 (or consider removing the answer).

Answer (score 8):

`boost::shared_ptr` is a requirement for modern C++ programming IMHO. That's why they added it to the standard with TR1. `boost::program_options`, `boost::bind`, and `boost::signal` are really nice if you know what they are for and how to use them. The last two tend to scare newcomers though.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using shared_ptr for years now.  It's just so useful, there's no reason that a project should be without it.

On top of that, I also use Bind/Function/Lambda for generic callback mechanisms -- especially useful when testing -- as well as Format for my general-purpose sprintf replacement.

Finally, it was just the other day when I used Variant in anger to solve a problem (a parser that could respond with a small, fixed set of unrelated token types).  The solution was very elegant, and I'm very happy with it.

---

Years have passed and times have changed, so time for an update.  SharedPtr and Function are now part of the Standard, and Bind and Lambda are obsoleted by actual language-level lambda functionality.

I still use Variant (which has also been standardized, but I'm not there yet), Format is largely replaced by fmtlib (which has also been standardized).

The big part of Boost that I use is Boost.Asio.  Which is in the process of being standardized.

Comment: I agree with all of the above -- except Lambda. I used it for a while, but it's so tortuous that I've abandoned it for all but the simplest expressions. Eagerly awaiting C++0x and its form of lambda expressions.

Comment: I agree that Boost.Lambda is full of all sorts of pitfalls -- as soon as I enter the realms of Unlambda or Protect, I give up and do it the old way, but it seems essential in extending callbacks in any half-decent way.  That said, I too await the C++0x implementation.

Answer (score 7):

We found boost::spirit pretty useful for a business solution to parse ECMAScript. Complex, but very nice!

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised to don't see yet between the answers [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread.html).

Comment: Now there's `std::thread`.

Answer (score 6):

Using tuples to iterate a map, like this:

```
string key, value;
BOOST_FOREACH(tie(key, value), my_map) { ... }
```

Using boost assign, I can intialize a map like this:

```
map<string, string> my_map = map_list_of("key1", "value1")("key2", "value2")("key3", "value3");
```

And using range adaptors and the pipe("|") operator I can iterate backwards over the values of a map(as an example):

```
BOOST_FOREACH(string value, my_multimap.equal_range("X") | map_values | reversed) { ... }
```

Comment: That's really cool. It has got me reading through the documentation for boost assignment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html

Answer (score 5):

You should check boost::program_options. It makes command line parsing much easier.

Answer (score 5):

I use Boost Pointer Containers in preference to a STL container of `shared_ptr`s.

Answer (score 4):

I use [boost::numeric::ublas::matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm) quite a bit.

Comment: This is considered to be an outdated library, I think.

Answer (score 3):

What I use the most is now available in the TR1:

- shared pointers
- array class

Now I also use pool classes and some other more specific things.

You understand now that Boost is meant to be useful to most programmers, that's why it's the test bed for the future standard library.

Answer (score 3):

I love boost::random and boost::asio and boost::filesystem, however boost::bind , boost::circular_buffer and boost::thread are very practical, smart pointers are ok but I prefer RAII instead as memory management

Comment: Smart pointers are RAII.

Comment: more precisely, Smart pointers give you RAII when there's no choice but to allocate memory dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, here is a new one I've found:
Instead of using *stricmp* I can use boost's *equals* function and pass in the is_iequal predicate
eg:
instead of

```
stricmp( "avalue", mystr.c_str() ) == 0
```

I can use

```
equals( "avalue", mystr, is_iequal() )
```

given:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace boost::algorithm;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my two cents:

- boost::scope_exit - no need to define RAII class just for one use
- boost::any
- boost::variant
- Boost Pointer Container Library (ptr_vector)
- Boost Pool Library
- boost::unordered_map / boost::unordered_set

Answer (score 3):

I use `boost::icl` quite a lot for text post-processing. Saved me quite a lot of time because otherwise I'd have to implement text-splitting myself...

`BOOST_FOREACH` is everywhere in my code :)

`boost::function` and `boost::bind` are an absolute must. Although now they are `std::function` and `std::bind`. These really help reduce the amount of unnecessary code and are just generally good for my designs (or my delusions).

I've recently started using `boost::interprocess::message_queue` and this is a great tool too.

I'd use a lot more, but Qt has native ways of doing a lot of things Boost does. If I ever have to program pure C++, I guess I'd become a `boost::junkie` :)

Answer (score 1):

Talking about boost::lexical_cast, why isn't something like 'format' a static member in the std::string library?
Almost all gui libs have something like CString::Format("%i") or QString::Number("%i") which return an initialised string.

Comment: e.g.:

`std::string = boost::format("Hello, %1% %2%") % "world" % "!!!").str();`

Comment: If you are willing to forgo type-safety, you can roll your own with vsnprintf(), ellipsis (...), va_list/stdarg.h, and a local (stack-based) buffer.

Comment: std::string already has 71 functions too many (by Herb Sutter's count, not mine). See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm for details: I think it has enough info to explain (a) why format needn't be in std::string, and (b) why it's better to write generic algorithms than class member functions anyway.

Comment: Or to put it another way, "C++ is like a foreign country: they do things differently there" ;-)

Comment: Boost to the rescue!  I guess Format isn't in the std lib because streams are apparently the greatest thing since sliced bread and format looks like nasty old 'c'.

Comment: Format's not part of the library because one of the challenges Stroustrup was posed as he was designing C++ was the construction of a type-safe formatted I/O library. Obviously, the result was what you see with iostreams. Apparently, no one had thought of interpolation at the time. Perhaps someone would like to write a formatstream, to make traditionalists feel more at home?

Comment: With variadic templates in C++11, you could make a typesafe version of `printf`. Of course, back when C++ was first standardized they were not yet available.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question should be reversed. Which part of you boost would you *not want* to use ?

In my experience pretty much all of it is interesting and useful in each problem domain.

You should spend time looking all around the boost documentation to find the areas that cover your interests.

One exception may be `boost::numeric::ublas` which is does its job, but [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) does it remarkably better.

Comment: I doubt the octonion library is used by many.